# A particle running on a treadmill?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If I put a particle moving at the speed of light on a treadmill, what will happen to the machine? (Ignore it might break and their size difference)
pardon me if the question is silly,because it's just my opinion

Answer (score 1):

if particle moves with light speed it can only has a zero mass. It's mean it will always move with light speed or collide with some physical object like treadmill and give it energy and momentum in the direction of particle movement

Comment: It would also mean the treadmill has to move at lightspeed, hence impossible.